# Java: Anybody have an example project using google protocol buffers over a network?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I'm not sure how to send messages with google protocol buffers to start, so an example with how to build a message, send it, and the reconstruct the message would be awesome.

Comment: I can't offer much Java wisdom, but you should be able to separate the two issues; a: transfer a binary stream over a network, and b: handle protobuf... finding examples of the two separately may be pretty simple.

Comment: Short answer is that you can send them over any mechanism. If you want RPC, Google hasn't open-sourced Stubby so you'll need to look into third-party plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outcome of a protobuf is a byte array that can be transported over many protocols like HTTP (using POST). If you want a low level RPC mechanism then there are many RPC plugins available. You can find the list [here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns#RPC_Implementations). You can also get the example usage on their respective websites.

Comment: I mean like over a DataInputStream

Comment: @DerNalia - that is not possible as protobuf's encoding is different than that of DataInputStream. But if you want to convert protobuf to some text base encoding like json (process is called transcoding) then look at protostuff: http://code.google.com/p/protostuff/

Answer (score 0):

http://www.javarants.com/2008/12/27/using-jax-rs-with-protocol-buffers-for-high-performance-rest-apis/

Kind of complicated though :)

Comment: And unnecessary -- it's unlikely performance is significantly better than with either plain JSON, or binary JSON (Smile)

Comment: binary JSON? JSON goes out the window when you use protobuffs - the data values are only generated/sent/parsed, no field names? @StaxMan

Comment: @TomChamberlain not really. Protobuf does use short int ids to as field ids, technique that other formats can and do use (Smile binary json for example uses back-references). But more importantly there are trade-offs where compactness is just one; and choice depends on usage. Most importantly, use of protobuf absolutely requires use, transfer and adoption of schema definition. This may or may not be worth the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly trivial if you are using Spring Boot:

http://spring.io/blog/2015/03/22/using-googl…

If you are using JavaScript as part of your set up at a front end, there are some gotchas such as jQuery trying to de-seralize your data under the hood etc. Better to use XMLHttpRequest and arraybuffer types if so.